# Throttle PySpark batch write to Event Hubs

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-eventhub

I am trying to write a script to send data to Event Hubs from a PySpark dataframe. This script should be able to use Spark to send anywhere from single events to millions. I have used [this guide](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-spark/blob/master/docs/PySpark/structured-streaming-pyspark.md) as a reference point; however, since I am using `df.write.format("eventhubs").options(**conf).save()` instead of using Structured Streaming, I am facing Timeout exceptions from EventHubs where Spark is sending events too quickly.

I see there is the maxEventsPerTrigger option, but it's only available for streaming queries.

How can I throttle the Spark write operation to ensure it doesn't overflow an Event Hub with 2 throughput units?

Specific error:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure. Task 3 in stage 60.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 3.3 in stage 60.0 (TID 784) (10.139.64.11 executor 30) com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.ServerBusyException: The request was terminated because the entity is being throttled. Error code : 50002. Sub error : 102. Please wait 4 seconds and try again.
```

Comment: You should experiment with `linger.ms` and/or `batch.size`
See here for more details:
https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/producer-configs.html#producerconfigs_batch.size

Answer (score 0):

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and I got below results:**

Install this libraire: `com.microsoft.azure:azure-eventhubs-spark_2.12:2.3.22`

[image]

**Please follow below syntax and  connection String Endpoint:**

> **Code:**

```
connectionString = "Endpoint=sb://<Namespase>.servicebus.windows.net/<Event_hub_name>;EntityPath=<Event_hub_name>;SharedAccessKeyName=<SAS_KEY_NAME>;SharedAccessKey=<SAS_Token"

ehConf = {}

ehConf['eventhubs.connectionString'] = sc._jvm.org.apache.spark.eventhubs.EventHubsUtils.encrypt(connectionString)


df1 = spark \
  .read \
  .format("eventhubs") \
  .options(**ehConf) \
  .load()

ds = df1 \
  .select("body") \
  .write \
  .format("eventhubs") \
  .options(**ehConf) \
  .save()
```

**Output:**

[image]
[image]

For more information follow this [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-spark/blob/master/docs/PySpark/structured-streaming-pyspark.md) reference.